# Intersection of Normal Subgroups is normal, set approach

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Assuming that we know that, given two normal subgroups $H,K$ of a group $G$ that their intersection is also a subgroup of $G$, the goal is to show that $H\cap K$ is also normal.  I saw a couple of approaches on the site, but I think this would suffice by using definitions themselves, so I have, for any element $g\in G$

$$gH\cap K=g\{x|x \in H \text{ and } x \in K\}=\{gx|gx \in H \text{ and } gx \in K\}$$
$$=\{xg|xg \in H \text{ and } xg\in K\}=\{x|x\in H \text{ and } x\in K\}g=H\cap Kg$$

Is this sufficient to show normality?

Comment: I think that you have a bit of a jump between the first and second lines.  This could be a complete proof, but explaining (in words) why those two sets are the same is the key component of the proof.

Comment: It might be clearer, using really the same approach that you have here, to have $g(H\cap K)=(gH)\cap (gK)$.  This is just writing your "and" as an intersection, but it makes some of the steps more obvious.

Comment: So, then the next step would be $\{gx|gx\in gH \text{ and } gx\in gK\}$ and then play off the fact that since these are normal subgroups, the left cosets equal the right cosets?

Comment: That set is correct, but it isn't equal to the previous step (because of an error in the previous step).  The end of the first line should be $\{gx|x\in H\text{ and }x\in K\}$.

Comment: Oh wait, so really that's all I have to change!  Since $H$ and $K$ are normal, then $g\{x|condition\}=\{gx|condition\}=\{xg|condition\}=\{x|condition\}g$?

Comment: The hard part is changing the objects from $gx$ to $xg$.

Comment: But it should be straightforward to go from $gx$ to $xg$ since that's a condition of normality of $x$ on both sets, given our information of $H$ and $K$?

Comment: @Lalaloopsy Yes, that would be the point exercise. So essentially your done.

Comment: Now I get it.  Thanks for the help.  I also thought the proof below was great, but I wanted to see where my error was from the set method above, and you made that very clear.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's the problem, $g(H\cap K)=g\{x:x\in H\text{ and }x\in K\}=\{gx:x\in H\text{ and }x\in K\}=\{gx:gx\in gH\text{ and }gx\in gK\}=\{gx:gx\in Hg\text{ and }gx\in Kg\}$.  Because $H$ and $K$ are normal, $gH=Hg$, but that doesn't change the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so being that $g\{x|x\in H$ and $x\in K\}=\{gx|x\in H$ and $x\in K\}\neq \{gx| gx\in H $ and $ gx\in K\}$. Since a set is usually written as $\{$elements$|$conditional$\}$ changing the elements in the set (in this case $gH\cap K$) doesn't change the conditional (in this case  $x\in H\cap K $ which isn't the same as $gx\in H\cap K$). Here is how I would prove the statement(You can skip this proof is you want to):

**Statement: $H,K\lhd G\implies H\cap K\lhd G$**

Proof: If $x\in H\cap K$ then $gxg^{-1}\in H$ since $x\in H\lhd G$ and $gxg^{-1}\in K$ since $x\in K\lhd G$ so $gxg^{-1}\in H\cap K$ which implies that $gH\cap K g^{-1}=H\cap K$ or $gH\cap K=H\cap Kg$

Comment: Okay, i like that fact that you explained why changing elements doesn't change conditional.  Very clear.  I like your approach.  Perhaps those reasons above are why there are not many set approaches to these types of problems.